# How to use fork and wait to run child process indefinitely?

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'm creating a program in which I am to allow the user to enter the length of a word, with the number of words corresponding to this length to be returned.

I have completed this aspect of it

My issue is as follows: I am supposed to have a child process to count and return the words corresponding to the length before asking the user again to enter another length. However, if a string of a certain length is 0, I am supposed to have the child process redo the count indefinitely, only being terminated by means of a separate terminal without terminating the parent process.

ANY help is appreciated.

My code is as follows

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int WordsCount(char *string,int len){

    int count=0,Wordcount=0;

    while(*string){

        //Checks for Delimeter
        if (*string== ' ' || *string== ',' || *string== '\t' || *string== '\n' || *string== '.' || *string== '!' || *string == '\0'){

            if (count==len){ // Checks If calculated length equals to User given length
                Wordcount++;
                count=0;
                string++;
            }
            else{
                count=0;
            }
        }
        else{
            count++;
        }

        string++;
    }
    return Wordcount; //Returns The Final Count of Words
}

int main()
{
    const char string[] = "Maids table how learn drift but purse stand yet set. Music me house could among oh as their."
    "Piqued our sister shy nature almost his wicket. Hand dear so we hour to. He we be hastily offence effects he service."
    "Sympathize it projection ye insipidity celebrated my pianoforte indulgence. Point his truth put style."
    "Elegance exercise as laughing proposal mistaken if. We up precaution an it solicitude acceptance invitation."
    "Acceptance middletons me if discretion boisterous travelling an. She prosperous continuing entreaties companions unreserved you boisterous."
    "Middleton sportsmen sir now cordially ask additions for. You ten occasional saw everything but conviction. Daughter"
    "returned quitting few are day advanced branched. Do enjoyment defective objection or we if favourite. At wonder afford so danger cannot former seeing."
    "Power visit charm money add heard new other put. Attended no indulged marriage is to judgment offering landlord. Parish so enable innate in formed missed."
    "Hand two was eat busy fail. Stand smart grave would in so. Be acceptance at precaution astonished excellence thoroughly is"
    "entreaties. Who decisively attachment has dispatched. Fruit defer in party me built under first. Forbade him but savings"
    "sending ham general. So play do in near park that pain.";

    int Length;

    printf("Enter Word Length?\n");

    scanf("%d",&Length);           //Reading Length of the word from User

    int result = WordsCount(string,Length);   // Return Count Storing.

    printf("Count = %d\n",result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably avoid variable names like `string`. It will likely cause you problems if you switch to a C++ compiler.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but try it.

```
    pid_t ret;
    int w,status;
ret = fork();
if(ret==-1){
    perror("Fork");
}
else if(ret==0) {
    printf("Enter Word Length?\n");
    scanf("%d",&length);
    int result=WordsCount(string,Length);
    if (result==0) {
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("Count = %d \n",result);
    }
}else{
    printf("Enter Word Length?\n");
    scanf("%d",&length);
    w = wait(&status);
    int result = WordsCount(string,Length);
}
```

Comment: And add printf("Count= %d",result) both end of else statements.

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to clearly understant what you want try to achieve but just in case...
I think that a thread/process that run indefinetely is a mistake except if something can change it's behavior during is "life". (not only wait for a human action)

Nevertheless, I think you should consider using a threads instead of forks. This will ensure that all threads die if the parent ends or is killed otherwise your child processes can remain running until someone kill them. ( human action or reboot )

whatever your choice is, you can easly find code sample for that with a little google search.
Rearding how to interrupt the child thread/process from another terminal, there is no easy way as it will be launch in the background.

the hard way : make the child control a listen a socket and make it exits when receiving a message.

a simpler way: make the child create a file upon start and control that the file still exist on each loop. Make the child exit if the file is deleted.

Another way (more elegant) could be to use linux signal. implement a signal listener and make it stop  if it catches a SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 signal.
see "man 2 signal" to get some help. The drawback is if your parent process/thread starts serveral childs, they will all stops upon signal reception.(stoping a specific child will not be possible)

Hope this will help.